# Slip of the tongue

Tags: english, american-english, grammaticality, errors

Just now, I had a slip of the tongue which resulted in a silly grammatical error. I said "if I had, I would not commented on it". I added "have" afterwards. My question is "do natives make such mistakes because of slips of the tongue?"

Comment: A slip of the tongue is a description, not a cause.

Comment: @ColinFine do natives make so silly a mistake sometimes?

Comment: All the time. Mostly nobody ever notices. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @jlawler I just hate it like sin, bro. I really hate the fact I missed putting in "have" there. Are you serious that even a native sometimes misses it and ends up saying "would + past participle"?

Comment: Trust me on this. Think about all the slips you've  made in your native language. English is usually spoken so fast that words drop out, and the grammar is full of processes that delete words and phrases whenever possible.

Comment: @ColinFine sorry for the wrong term. I meant "grammatical slips"

Comment: Doing syntax at speed is difficult. In any sentence with  two or more pronouns in it I am as likely to switch the pronouns around as not.

Comment: @jlawler okay, I do understand it. But, we are talking about "would + past participle" without "have". It's a shameful mistake to me myself, dude. But, I always consider any mistake normal if it's also made by the native. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: _Would_ plus _have_ is normally pronounced ['wʊɾə] in American English, and that final shwa is deleted pretty often, especially before a vowel. _Have_ as an auxiliary is almost never pronounced [hæv]; much more common is /v/ or /ə/, both of which get lost easily. This is because auxiliaries are as unstressed as possible; they're meaningless, so they're disposable, and people will assume they're there when they aren't because they can predict them, and they like hearing what they expect.

Comment: @jlawler now you are like an angelic guy to me. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @jlawler but, dude, I forgot to stress that it was not about "would + past participle", but "would + not + past participle". Do you think natives also make such a grammatical slip?

Comment: ['wʊɾə] is the affirmative, ['wʊdnə] is the negative. Sometimes it's three syllables, ['wʊdənə]. And it's not a "slip". Written words are not how the language is spoken; they're just a way to represent some parts of the language, like Chinese characters. Nobody talks like writing.

Comment: Thanks for the unlimoted patience jlawler :)